# Fuera de límites en arrays Matlab/Python

Tags: python, array, matrices, numpy, matlab

En Matlab tengo el siguiente código:

```
imagen = imread('imagen.jpg');
escala = cambiatam(ll); %reducción de la imagen   
Spixel = 40000
I_reducida = imresize(imagen,escala);
[nfila,ncolum,~]=size(I_reducida);
[LSP,N] = superpixels(I_reducida,Spixel)
llave_pixelada = zeros(size(I_reducida),'like',I_reducida);
idx = label2idx(LSP); 
    for labelVal = 1:N     
        redIdx = idx{labelVal};     
        greenIdx = idx{labelVal}+nfila*ncolum;     
        blueIdx = idx{labelVal}+2*nfila*ncolum;   
        llave_pixelada(redIdx) = mean(I_reducida(redIdx));     
        llave_pixelada(greenIdx) = mean(I_reducida(greenIdx));     
        llave_pixelada(blueIdx) = mean(I_reducida(blueIdx));        
end
```

Lo que hace el código de arriba es convertir una matriz de etiquetas (LSP) en índices. Dicha matriz de etiquetas indican los superpíxeles de una imagen segmentada: la imagen está segmentada en 37422 superpíxeles ÚTILES (agrupaciones grandes de píxeles) y cada región tiene una etiqueta (habrá unos píxeles que tengan la etiqueta 1,2,3... hasta 37422).

Dichos pixeles se pasan a índices (idx), donde la matriz de etiquetas se convierte en matriz de celdas de índices lineales. Luego se forma una imagen a raíz de esas matrices de celdas mediante los valores redIdx, blueIdx y greenIdx.

Al final de la iteración, redIdx es una matriz 2x1 con los valores finales del bucle (289485, 289486) y luego se hace los siguiente:

```
 llave_pixelada(redIdx) = mean(I_reducida(redIdx));
```

I_reducida es la imagen previa a la segmentación, simplemente reescalada a una imagen 366x791, al igual que llave_pixelada (solo que esta es de ceros).

Cuando se hace I_reducida(redIdx), el resultado final es una matriz 2x1 que vale (94, 83) (y luego hace la media) y si hago `imshow(llave_pixelada(redIdx)` se me muestra la imagen ya segmentada y en rojo. Lo mismo para los canales verde y azul que hacen que se muestre ya finalmente la imagen segmentada de la imagen original.

**EL PROBLEMA** viene cuando implemento esa misma línea de código en Python. El código es el siguiente:

```
im = mpimg.imread('imagen.jpg')
spixel = 40000 
escala = ct.cambiatam(ll)
im_reducida = rescale(ll, escala, multichannel = True)
[M,N,_] = im_reducida.shape
LSP = seg.slic(im_reducida, n_segments=spixel, start_label=1)
llave_pixelada = np.zeros(im_reducida.shape)

idx = lb.label2idx(LSP)
for i in range(np.max(LSP)):
    redIdx = idx[i]
    greenIdx = idx[i]+M*N     
    blueIdx = idx[i]+2*M*N
    llave_pixelada[redIdx] = np.mean(im_reducida[redIdx])
    llave_pixelada[greenIdx] = np.mean(im_reducida[greenIdx])
    llave_pixelada[blueIdx] = np.mean(im_reducida[blueIdx])
```

Y al hacer `llave_pixelada[redIdx] = np.mean(im_reducida[redIdx])` me sale el siguiente error: index 370 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 369.

Esto se debe porque justo en la primera iteración, el primer array de idx vale idx[0] = 1,2,3,**370**,371,372,739,740,741, mientras que en MATLAB vale idx{1} = 1,2,3,4,369,370,735,736,737,1101,1467, pero sin embargo en MATLAB funciona. Creo que el error debe estar en la expresión de  `llave_pixelada[redIdx] = np.mean(im_reducida[redIdx])`, pero no sabría cómo arreglarlo.

Muchas gracias de antemano a los que podáis ayudarme. Cualquier duda acerca del código la responderé de inmediato.

El dato de escala en ambos programas es 0.38

FUNCIÓN LABEL2IDX

```
import numpy as np

def label2idx(label_arr):
    return [
        np.where(label_arr.T.ravel() == i)[0] + 1
        for i in range(1, np.max(label_arr) + 1)]
```

[image: Imagen de MATLAB]
[image: Imagen de Python]

Comment: Es posible que incluyas la imagen que estas usando en la pregunta?

Comment: No conozco mucho Matlab, pero el error es claro estas intentando acceder a un indice 370 que esta por fuera del array cuyo size es 379. La diferencia entre python y Matlab, es que los indices en python empiezan en 0 y en Matlab empiezan en 1. Entonces lo mas probable es que el tema sea por ahi.

Comment: Un `-1` soluciona todo

Comment: No creo que tenga que ver con que empiece en 0 o 1, ya que la imagen de Matlab también tiene que iterar más allá del 370 y de hecho lo hace, ahora añado la imagen @JavierCárdenas, las voy a guardar ya que ambas surgen de un proceso más tocho que hacen Python y Matlab y pueden diferir un poco pese a que sea 99% la misma

Comment: @JavierCárdenas he añadido también el dato de escala, la imagen en Python incluye los ejes X e Y pero creo que con la original de Matlab no habría problema.

Comment: De donde sale `label2idx`? Parece que retorna los indices con un error de _off-by-1_. Probablemente baste con hacer `idx = lb.label2idx(LSP)-1`

Comment: justo ahora acabo de incluir la definición de esa función @abulafia

Comment: Efectivamente esa funcion presupone indices entre 1 y N, en lugar de entre 0 y N-1. O la arreglas o pones el -1 que indicaba en mi anterior comentario. Mejor arreglarla por si se usa en otros sitios

Comment: el -1 lo he probado en tu primer comentario y me da otro error justo en esa misma línea. Luego en lo otro hago ````for i in range(np.max(LSP)-1):``` y me sale el mismo error que el original.

Como curiosidad, en MATLAB si quito las llave_pixeladas del bucle y sólo dejo los red, blue, green Idx, si fuera del bucle hago llave_pixelada(redIdx) (sin asignar a nada) me devuevle una matriz 2x1 de valor (0, 0), siendo redIdx del mismo tamaño, pero con valores (287880, 287786).

Comment: Si hago lo mismo en Python (bucle hasta N, que es el np.max(LSP)) y llave_pixelada[redIdx] me sale el error: index 287880 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 369

Comment: @javiercárdenas ahí he dejado información extra, muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda